# Алгоритм php печатать буквы по порядку

Tags: php, алгоритм

```
$s =
[
    "a",
    "b",
    "c",
    "d",
    "e",
    "f",
];

$i = 0;

while(true)
{
    var_dump($s[$i++ % count($s)]);
}
```

Как создать такой алгоритм, чтобы $i постоянно увеличивалась и циклом печаталась каждая буква abcd... по порядку и по циклу abcdefabcdefabcdefabc...
Приведенный выше пример не работает.

Comment: почему не работает? вполне себе работает

Comment: Наверное просто по таймауту выбивает, а так работает.

Answer (score 1):

Твой цикл бесконечен. Нет из него "выхода". не знаю что такое `var_dump`, но я бы по твоему запросу вывода `abcdefabcdefabcdefabc` использовал бы `echo`.

в итоге код у меня получился таковым (цикл обрывается на 30 символе):

```
$s =
[
    "a",
    "b",
    "c",
    "d",
    "e",
    "f",
];

$i = 0;

while(true)
{
    echo $s[$i % count($s)];
    if ($i == 30){
       break;
    }
$i++;
}
```

Comment: `не знаю что такое var_dump` - а стОит ;-)